# ConstraintLayout - avoid overlapping

Tags: android, text, textview, android-constraintlayout

There is a `ConstraintLayout` layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="small text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="small text"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It is displayed like this:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Now is Ok, but if i change
`android:text="small text"` to `android:text="big teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeext"` then views will overlap each other..

I'm need to make sure that with a small text there is a "wrap content", as I actually did on the screenshot above, but with a larger text, the text views must occupy a maximum of about 40 percent horizontally of the parent. Well also that the text was not transferred - I do `android: ellipsize =" end "` and `android: singleLine =" true`.

This is how it should be (edited in Photoshop for demonstration):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
How do this with ConstraintLayout or if can't - with others layouts?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can also do it using **Guideline** and **layout_constraintWidth_default** property as in below example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="sdtessdsdsdsdsdsdsdsddsdsdxt"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ddddddsdssdsdsdsdsdsdddt"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This will work only if you use 'app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' and 'app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' *don't use* -> 'constraintStart_toStarttOf' and 'constraintEnd_toEndOf'

Answer (score 26):

The following attribute works:

```
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

> WRAP_CONTENT : enforcing constraints (Added in 1.1)
>   If a dimension is set to WRAP_CONTENT, in versions before 1.1 they will be treated as a literal dimension -- meaning, constraints will not limit the resulting dimension. While in general this is enough (and faster), in some situations, you might want to use WRAP_CONTENT, yet keep enforcing constraints to limit the resulting dimension. In that case, you can add one of the corresponding attribute:
>
> app:layout_constrainedWidth=”true|false”
>   app:layout_constrainedHeight=”true|false”

Answer (score 3):

> You can do like this :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="small text"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button11"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="small textsfdgdfjkghkdfhgjkdfhgkhgkhkjjkgfkgjkfgjkgjkjgfdkj"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button10" />
```

Comment: or otherwise 2nd option you have to give fix width to button if you want to android: ellipsize =" end ".

Comment: This does not really work. One of the buttons will be dependent on the other one and that one will decide positioning.

Answer (score 2):

If constraint is from left/right

```
    set vertical guideline
    set component layout_width = 0dp
```

If constraint is from top/bottom

```
    set horizontal guideline
    set component layout_height = 0dp
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a horizontal chain and a 'app:layout_constraintWidth_percent'.

The 'spread_inside' chain type would make the buttons stick to the parent edges, it's added on the first button in chain.
[image]

The guidelines role is performed by the 'app:layout_constraintWidth_percent' on each button. It is set to 0.5 on both buttons. This will make each of them occupy maximum half of the available horizontal space.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button10"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:text="bguigui uegerger er ergre greg  gre grefufifu "
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button11"/>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button11"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:text="aaa jjjk kkkl"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```